# R lattice set default arguments

Tags: r, set, default, lattice

I want to specify some options in a levelplot() of the R package lattice. I set the argument `scales` and this works fine:

```
scales = list(x = list(at = c(0:8*16 +.5),
                   cex = 0), 
          y = list(at = c(0:8*16+.5),
                   cex = 0))
```

Now, I want to have this argument as default. I.e. I want to have this scales in each `levelplot()` in the session without specifying this argument each time. I tried to do this with `lattice.options()` but I don't know how.

Comment: One way would be to store this list in a variable and call this variable every time you use `levelplot`.

Answer (score 1):

How about lattice::trellis.par.set()?

Answer (score 0):

Settings objects are retrieved with trellis.par.get("name of component to be set"). as example:

```
plot.line.settings <- trellis.par.get("plot.line")
```

The plot.line.settings object is list and its items can be changed/update. Then you set the global settings:

```
trellis.par.set("plot.line", plot.line.settings)
```

To make the settings applicable to any future opened devices, must set retain argument to TRUE when opening a device.